# Error when parsing string to double in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, parsing, read.csv

I am trying to read data from a CSV file using Dart. The code I am using reads the lines from the file and splits them into columns using the split() method. One of the columns contains numeric data in string format, which I need to convert to a double. However, when I try to parse the string using the double.parse() method, I get a FormatException: Invalid double error. (the string is "1.5" which should work normally)

```
map[columns[5]] = (map[columns[5]] ?? 0) + double.parse(columns[3]);
```

this is the error displayed :

```
Reading from file: .\\test.csv
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Invalid double
"1.5"
#0      double.parse (dart:core-patch/double_patch.dart:112:28)
#1      main (...)
#2      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:295:33)
#3      _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:26)
```

I have tried using the trim() method to remove any whitespace characters from the string before parsing it, but the error persists. I have also checked the data in the CSV file and confirmed that it is correctly formatted as a decimal number.

Comment: Can you share the `test.csv` source code?  A CSV parser should not return the value `"1.5"` unless that value is quoted more than once (`""1.5""`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message:

> ```
> FormatException: Invalid double
> "1.5"
> ```

indicates that you're calling `double.parse` on the string `"1.5"` that *includes the double-quote characters*.  You must strip them off first.  There are a number of different ways that you could do that, for example:

```dart
String unquote(String s) =>
    (s.length < 2 || !s.startsWith('"') || !s.endsWith('"'))
        ? s
        : s.substring(1, s.length - 1);

void main() {
  var s = '"1.5"';
  print(s); // Prints: "1.5"
  print(unquote(s)); // Prints: 1.5
  print(double.parse(unquote(s))); // Prints: 1.5
}
```

Or even better would be to use a proper CSV parser, which should handle unquoting fields for you.  Note that naively using `String.split` likely would result in incorrect results if your CSV file includes strings with embedded commas. (I have not personally used it, but [`package:csv`](https://pub.dev/packages/csv) probably would be suitable.)

Answer (score 0):

**You will follow like this way**

```
void main() {
var value1 = "1.5";
var value2 = double.parse(value1);
print(value1);
print(value2);

var value3 = value2 + double.parse(value1);
print(value3);
}
```

**Answer**
[image: look into this image]

Answer (score 0):

This code is from the Udemy Flutter Course, coding with Andrea.

You need to fix your replaceAll('"', '');

- answer form coding with Andrea